# Performance advantage - multiple PowerShells vs Background-Jobs

Tags: performance, powershell

I made a programm which is starting multiple Background-Jobs at the same time. Currently the process is taking several hours (sometimes 3 hours, sometimes up to 6 hours depending on the files and size).

Is there any advantage in rewriting the code so it doesn't start all the processes in the same Shell using Background-Jobs but instead starts a PowerShell for each individual Process? Or isn't there any big difference between both of them?

```
$handler_button1_Click= 
{
    if ($checkBox1.Checked)    { 
    Try{
    $job1 = start-jobhere {& C:\Users\mosermich\Desktop\Extractor\Ressources\adp_staging.bat} -Name "ADP-DATA"
    $listBox1.Items.Add("ADP-staging läuft...")
    }catch [System.Exception]{}
    }

    if ($checkBox2.Checked)    { 
    Try{ 
    $job2 = start-jobhere {& C:\Users\mosermich\Desktop\Extractor\Ressources\kdp_staging.bat} -Name "KDP-DATA"
    $listBox1.Items.Add("KDP-staging läuft...")
    }catch [System.Exception]{}
    }

    if ($checkBox3.Checked)    { 
    Try{ 
    $job3 = start-jobhere { & C:\Users\mosermich\Desktop\Extractor\Ressources\mdp_staging.bat} -Name "MDP-DATA"
    $listBox1.Items.Add("MDP-staging läuft...")
    }catch [System.Exception]{}
    }

    if ($checkBox4.Checked)    { 
    Try{ 
    $job4 = start-jobhere { & C:\Users\mosermich\Desktop\Extractor\Ressources\zdlb_staging.bat} -Name "ZDL-B-DATA"
    $listBox1.Items.Add("ZDLB-staging läuft...")
    }catch [System.Exception]{}
    }

    if ($checkBox5.Checked)    { 
    Try{ 
    $job5 = start-jobhere { & C:\Users\mosermich\Desktop\Extractor\Ressources\zdls_staging.bat} -Name "ZDL-S-DATA"
    $listBox1.Items.Add("ZDLS-staging läuft...")
    }catch [System.Exception]{}
    }

    if ($checkBox6.Checked)    { 
    Try{ 
    $job6 = start-jobhere { & C:\Users\mosermich\Desktop\Extractor\Ressources\zub_staging.bat} -Name "ZUBOFI-DATA"
    $listBox1.Items.Add("ZUBOFI-staging läuft...")
    }catch [System.Exception]{}
    }

    if ($checkBox7.Checked)    { 
    Try{ 
    $job7 = start-jobhere { & C:\Users\mosermich\Desktop\Extractor\Ressources\adp_staging_error.bat} -Name "ADP-ERR"
    $listBox1.Items.Add("ADP-Error-staging läuft...")
    }catch [System.Exception]{}
    }

    if ($checkBox8.Checked)    { 
    Try{  
    $job8 = start-jobhere { & C:\Users\mosermich\Desktop\Extractor\Ressources\kdp_staging_error.bat} -Name "KDP-ERR"
    $listBox1.Items.Add("KDP-Error-staging läuft...")
    }catch [System.Exception]{}
    }

    if ($checkBox9.Checked)    { 
    Try{  
    $job9 = start-jobhere { & C:\Users\mosermich\Desktop\Extractor\Ressources\mdp_staging_error.bat} -Name "MDP-ERR"
    $listBox1.Items.Add("MDP-Error-staging läuft...")
    }catch [System.Exception]{}
    }

    if ($checkBox10.Checked)    { 
    Try{  
    $job10 = start-jobhere { & C:\Users\mosermich\Desktop\Extractor\Ressources\zdlb_staging_error.bat} -Name "ZDL-B-ERR"
    $listBox1.Items.Add("ZDL-B-Error-staging läuft...")
    }catch [System.Exception]{}
    }

    if ($checkBox11.Checked)    { 
    Try{  
    $job11 = start-jobhere { & C:\Users\mosermich\Desktop\Extractor\Ressources\zdls_staging_error.bat} -Name "ZDL-S-ERR"
    $listBox1.Items.Add("ZDL-S-Error-staging läuft...")
    }catch [System.Exception]{}
    }

    if ($checkBox12.Checked)    { 
    Try{  
    $job12 = start-jobhere { & C:\Users\mosermich\Desktop\Extractor\Ressources\zub_staging_error.bat} -Name "ZUBOFI-ERR"
    $listBox1.Items.Add("ZUBOFI-Error-staging läuft...")
    }catch [System.Exception]{}
    }

    if ($listBox1.Items.Count -eq 0) {
    $listBox1.Items.Add("No-Data!") 
    }

    Get-Job | Wait-Job | Where State -eq "Running"


    $listBox1.Items.Add("All Jobs have been succesfully finished")

    }else{}
```

Comment: Short answer: It depends. But probably not. If you want to improve performance you have to determine the bottle neck e. g. which ressource is used. Due to your hint that the runtime depends on file and size I would suggest to review your script. Maybe you are calling Get-ChildItem multiple times. What is your script doing?

Comment: I provided the code in my question. It basically calls different .bat files which have SQL code written in them to extract data from my Oracle-Database tables. (I know this code could probably be written much much  shorter but i just recently got started with PowerShell.

Comment: Yes, you could implement it shorter ;-). However since you are extracting data from an oracle db, your bottle neck is most likely IO (db / file). You should now check whether you can improve your SQL...

Comment: Im going to take a closer look at my SQL Query's thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I guess) you won't see a big difference as spawning background jobs with `Start-Job` or calling comdlets with the `-AsJob` actually creates new instances of the PowerShell executable - you can see that with task manager / process explorer etc.

If you create a lot of background jobs simultaneously then it might be the case that there is quite a big of overhead in creating and scheduling those jobs compared to their actual workload. In this case you may want to take a look at PowerShell runspaces which are more lightweight. In particular you can take a look at the excellent [PoshRSJob](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob) module which makes working with runspaces look like working with the 'regular' PowerShell jobs. It also includes functionality to queue up tasks so that you don't execute 1000 tasks concurrently but only e.g. 8 at any given time.

Comment: Cool! Im going to have a look at those PoshRSJob's you suggested. Thank you.